# Is there single a word for a single animal of a species?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for a single animal of a species?

Example sentence

> the tapir is a very rare species, for example lets observe this {insert word here}

Comment: Yes, but they are all different, depending on the species. :)

Comment: Or maybe you want ***specimen***?

Comment: Please provide an example sentence where this word would fit.

Comment: the tapir is a very rare species, for example lets observe this {insert word here}

Comment: maybe individual?

Comment: In that sentence you could use: ***one*** or ***specimen***  or even ***animal*** and could optionally use  *particular* in front of if.

Comment: A combination of the previous proposals gives ... an "individual specimen".

Comment: ^@Flexin or you can use species sample, especially for a laboratory specimen/animal specimen. (In this context it describes that you're in a lab examining the tapir and suggest to observe this tapir).

Comment: @Graffito- "individual specimen" is good.

Comment: What's wrong with simply "tapir"?

Comment: Note that there are [five living species of tapir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapir)—one in Southeast Asia and four in South and Central America. So unless you've already identified which of the five species you're talking about, you wouldn't want to say "The tapir is a very rare species."

Answer (score 3):

> The tapir is a very rare species; for example, let's observe this individual.

or

> The tapir is a very rare species; for example, let's observe this particular specimen.

or even

> The tapir is a very rare species; for example, let's observe this one.

Answer (score 1):

(The best answer is **specimen** mentioned in comments and existing answers)

An alternative is **exemplar**

An [exemplar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exemplar) is a typical or representative specimen.

When to use: If you want to draw an inference about the entire species from study of a single individual then **exemplar** is slightly better than **specimen**, since a specimen could be an outlier, which is not helpful for inference about the entire species, but an exemplar is definitely representative and useful in this regard.